# Dreaming an app for editing wav file..by script

Tags: audio

I need an app like this.

I want to mux an audio file to make it syncro with video

using avidemux and cutting and paste frames

```
one: lead to crash

two: audio is full of strange popping and crackling sounds
```

So the solution is using avidemux to compare two video files

take the old good vi editor and make a file like this

```
#videoframes  operation

    32   delete from 0 to 32
    0+40 copy
    1954 add 40ms
    2685 add 40ms
    3139 add 39ms
    3230 add 40ms
    3278 add 40ms
    .....
```

Then i can use audacity import the wav file of video

and make the fixes one by one...but is really boring.

So the question is...is possible to editing a wav file

with a cli program?

This ideal program can use a script like this

```
import file.wav
0-32 cut
0-40 copy
1944 goto paste     
2020 goto paste..
save filenew.wav
```

A program like this did exist?

I know audacity can use dcop for "automation"

but i prefer to work with cli,more fast and nice

Comment: try [sox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoX)

Comment: You can do some weird magic with `ffmpeg`, if your scripting wizardry is good enough.